# Assigning an object to a list of objects in VB.NET does not store the value

Tags: vb.net, list, object, reference

I'm currently writing a program that shrinks images down to 16x16 pixels and calculates the difference with a simple self-written algorithm. For this to work, I want to get all files from a certain directory and store them into a list of objects, which looks like this:

```
Dim lFile As New List(Of cFile)
```

The object itself consists of the filepath string and the 16 by 16 macro image:

```
Class cFile
    Public sFilepath As String
    Public imageResized As Image
End Class
```

In order to add new items to the file list, I have created a new object that gets modified and is used for adding the new item(s) to the list:

```
Static Test As New cFile
Test.imageResized = ResizeImage(PictureBox1.Image)
Test.sFilepath = "image 1"
lFile.Add(Test)
```

Now here's my problem: Assigning the object to a new item in the list will somehow only assign it "ByReference" (I honestly have no clue how to call this or what I have to search for). What I want is the new item of the list to stay and not change when changing "Test" gets something new.
The code is a bit bigger, but I cut out the unimportant part for reasons of clarity. I would be really happy if someone could help me. Thanks!

Comment: Why Static? What happens if you just put "Dim Test as New cfile"?

Comment: `Dim Test As New cFile` should work - no context where this code is though

Answer (score 0):

That's how classes, which are reference types, work.  If you were to declare `cFile` as a structure then it would be a value type and behave how you want.

I'm not sure that that is the right solution though.  If you're changing the contents of a `cFile` object then that alone indicates that it should be a class.

The vast majority of types in the .NET Framework are classes and there's good reason for that.  I would suggest that you just need to change the way you think and work with types to use classes properly.

If you really do need to change a `cFile` object after adding it to the list, you should make a copy and change that.  You could make your class implement `IClonable` and do the copying internally.  It's hard to say what's the best option without a more complete description of what you're actually trying to achieve, rather than just how you're trying to achieve it.